# Why is there still CORS error if response has allow origin set to all?

Tags: javascript, express, cors

I have a react.js front end react app calling a node.js backend api. They are running on different ports. I have the following set in the backend response header.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```

I am still seeing the following CORS error when it calls the backend.

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/feed/post' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Making Post and Get requests with no custom header values.

Comment: Your custom CORS middleware doesn't handle [pre-flight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). Please just use the industry standard [cors middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware

```
$ npm install cors
```

in your `app.js` add this

```
const cors = require("cors");
//add in your middlewares
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Also added app.options('*', cors()) to my app.js. Still getting the error

Comment: app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true })); Node.js should give the option of 'cors' as follows, and the option of 'header' should also be given in reaction.

Comment: Looks like this needs to be set before the other app.use() ones. Otherwise will not work.